# SharePoint Custom Web Part throws SELECT permission denied on object 'xxx', database 'yyy', owner 'dbo'

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I have created a Custom Web Part in SharePoint 2007 using VS 2008 on the dev server. It uses the SQL DB. Everything works fine on my server with testing db which I recreated from the backup client gave me.

Now I'm moving it over to the clients' production server. I was able to deploy, install and activate it.

But when I'm trying to add the web part to the page, it throws a dialogbox with "An error occured while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details".

This is what I see in the LOG file: **... SELECT permission denied on object 'xxx', database 'yyy', owner 'dbo' ...**

The Web Part accesses the DB using the escalated priveleges, i.e. using the portal app pool service account. This account has proper rights to access the DB. I don't understand what can cause the problem.

Any help figuring out what causes the error is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Code pasted in comment included here to add formatting:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() 
{ 
    using (WAStockBinEntities context = new WAStockBinEntities()) 
    { 
        var userStockBin = (from stockBins in context.T1view_SP_StockBin 
                            where stockBins.ADName == currUserName 
                            select stockBins) .ToList().FirstOrDefault(); 

        StockRoomNumber.Text = userStockBin.Stockroom; 
        BinNumber.Text = userStockBin.BIN; 
    } 
});
```

Comment: How are you accessing the database?  Can you post some code?

Comment: Are you using SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges?  That is not really clear to me from your question.

Comment: Are you querying the SharePoint database? If it is so, it is highly recommended not to query the SP database directly.

Comment: Kyle Trauberman,
I use Linq to Entities and this is the code snippet:

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (WAStockBinEntities context = new WAStockBinEntities())
    {
        var userStockBin = (from stockBins in context.T1view_SP_StockBin
                            where stockBins.ADName == currUserName
                            select stockBins)
               .ToList().FirstOrDefault();

        StockRoomNumber.Text = userStockBin.Stockroom;
        BinNumber.Text = userStockBin.BIN;
    }
});

Comment: JD, yes, I'm using SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges

Comment: NLV, no, it is not a SharePoint DB, it's my client's SQL Database with business data.

Comment: Have you attempted to connect to the database with the account in question?  I've seen situations where the login isn't tied in with a user (i.e. restoring a backup).

Answer (score 1):

`SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` does not affect the user that LINQ uses to access the database.  I would look at the connection string that LINQ is using to access the database and ensure that the user referenced in the connection string has permissions to the database

You can check the connection string that is being used by calling the `Connection.ConnectionString` property of the data context.

```
using (WAStockBinEntities context = new WAStockBinEntities()) 
{ 
    return context.Connection.ConnectionString;
}
```